# Hardware acceleration unavailable under Chrome with proprietary fglrx driver

Tags: drivers, ati, video, google-chrome, hardware-acceleration

When I fullscreen a HD YouTube video or do other stuff that should be hardware accelerated, Chrome slows to a crawl. Taking a look at `chrome://gpu` shows this:

```
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable  
Flash: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable  
Flash Stage3D: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable  
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable  
Compositing: Software only, threaded. Hardware acceleration unavailable  
Rasterization: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable  
Threaded Rasterization: Unavailable  
Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable  
Video Encode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable  
WebGL: Unavailable
```

Which explains the stuttering video playback. However I can't find a way to enable hardware acceleration. Under `chrome://flags` I have `Override software rendering list` enabled and `Disable WebGL` is disabled. Also under Chrome's settings I have `Use hardware acceleration when available` checked.

I'm using the proprietary Radeon driver for my Radeon R9 290 video card:

[image]

Any ideas what I can do to make Chrome use my video card for hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 4):

It might be because you don't have VDPAU (Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix) libraries installed.

Try running the following command

```
sudo apt-get install vdpau-va-driver libvdpau1 libvdpau-va-gl1 libva-glx1
```

and then restarting chrome completely (all its windows).

Answer (score 0):

By default, Chrome(ium) doesn't compile the hardware acceleration code for Linux or for Mac and only compiles it for Windows and Chrome OS (for various reasons), so even if you override the software rendering list, and even if that list is completely green, hardware acceleration still won't be used.

I have builds of Chromium [Beta](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta) and [Dev](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-dev) that do enable hardware acceleration, but I'm not entirely sure that it works for ATI (it should). Note that you need to have at least `libva1` and `libva-x11-1` installed.